# Quartz Scheduler not working in multithreaded service

Tags: .net, multithreading, multiprocessing, quartz-scheduler, quartz.net

I have a piece of code which will create jobs using Quartz. This code will be called by multiple threads

```
 ISchedulerFactory fac = new StdSchedulerFactory();
                sched = fac.GetScheduler();

// schedele job

   sched.ScheduleJob(job1, trigger1);
                sched.Shutdown();
```

some times I am geting error message while getting the scheduler

Scheduler with name '{0}' already exists.

As pere some forum suggeton If i move getscheduler logic to singleton class, it is working fine without any issue. I am not sure why we need to move it to a singleton class.

I really don't understand what is causing the problem.

Comment: are you proxying to remote scheduler with either jmx or rmi?

Comment: I am using .Net version of Quartz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This code will be called by multiple threads

With this, it is implicit that race conditions can occur between calling threads while instantiating the scheduler instance. 
And it is logical that creating a scheduler with the same name should be prevented. Probably, the code in quartz which is creating a scheduler instance is not thread safe. :-)

Comment: can you please explain. why it is not preferred to have multiple schedulers with the same name. I am thinking If each thread is allowed to have shecduler with the same name once the work is done , I can shutdown the scheduler at that moment itself. with singleton, I can't sutdown the scheduler, I 've to keeep the scheduler until the whole system is completely unloaded.

Comment: scheduler name might be the primary key for the scheduler instance, that's why you are not able to create 
multiple instance with the same name. 
Your concurrent threads are trying to instantiate the scheduler at the same time. So the race condition is occuring.
What your desire might be to get an instance of scheduler which is already created and distribute it to your 
concurrent threads. But unfortunately that's not possible as getScheduler() is quartz code.